# How to integration testing of internal POST requests using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project using Django Rest Framework with two apps (`events` and `logs`) and associated endpoints `/events` and `/logs`

Clients can POST to `/events` some information about an event, the processing of this will record a log in the `logs` app model. The logs can then be retrieved using GET on `/logs`.

Whilst the events view can update through the logs view directly, I wanted to implement this through a POST call to `/logs` call to keep the interfaces more well defined and easier to split out into a completely separate service if required. The POST call is handled using `requests` package as follows:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
import requests

class Events(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        # Some event handling code...

        # Record log
        log_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('logs'))
        requests.post(log_url, data=event)
```

To test this works I boot up the server and do:

- POST /events/ (post some JSON data)
- GET /logs/

In this case I see some log data returned from the GET request, so I know that e2e the implementation works. However, when I try to automate this using `django.test.LiveServerTestCase` the response is always empty.

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient

class AppsEndpointTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def test_post_event_retrieve_logs(self):

        events_endpoint = self.live_server_url + '/events/'
        logs_endpoint = self.live_server_url + '/logs/'
        client = RequestsClient()

        # POST an application which we know will trigger an event
        client.post(events_endpoint, { 'event_code' : 'TEST_EVENT' })

        # Check the event is returned
        response = client.get(logs_endpoint)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn('TEST_EVENT', [log['event_code'] for logs in response.json()])
        # Assertion fails, response is empty
```

I am assuming the call to `request.build_absolute_uri()` is part of the problem and that the request that comes in doesn't have a proper hostname to build the URL from. I can't see any of the server logging when the test case is run, which has led me to this blocking point.

Why doesn't this work when using `LiveServerTestCase`?

Comment: I'm little bit confused by your explanation. You're sending both requests (GET and POST) to the same endpoint (`event_endpoint`) and from the description it seems that the `Events ApiView` should only handle `post` requests

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated the code to make GET request to `/logs/` endpoint. This was the original intention, and is what is not working for me.

Comment: Ah, ok. Did you try to use any other `TestCase` server? DRF has modified versions of Django test cases http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#test-cases but I guess they only differ in client

Comment: I don't think Django TestCase or TransactionTestCase would work as they don't boot up a server instance to be able to handle the POST request. I checked with the the DRF instance (APILiveServerTestCase), and that makes no difference. As you say, I think it only changes the client.

Comment: You could try to modify your test to make post request directly to logs endpoint. This way you'll be sure that the problem is in fact about `request.build_absolute_uri()`. Have you already tried that or does this require changes in your views?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I passed the parameter `--liveserver localhost:8081` and verified that was being used and then hardcoded the view to use that, with no success. It seems like something unusual is happening inside `requests.post(...)`. No code following this statement is executed. I assume there is some error/exception going on, but don't get any logs from the test runner. Going to have to break out the debugger I think.

Comment: I have found what is going wrong, will update the answer when I have finished investigating. `rest_framework.test.RequestsClient` doesn't work how I was expecting. The request is not sent as 'application/json' and is received by the BE as 'application/octet-stream'. If the call is changed to use the `self.client.post(...)` it works OK. I assume it's something to do with the fudge code to make the post work with a top level as list instead of dict.